# Numpy add array of shape NxD to NxK into the first D in array NxK

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [0, 2, 2, 3, 4]])
```

and

```
b = np.array([[1, 1],
              [2, 2],
              [3, 3]])
```

I want to one array where I am adding the values of `b` to the first two columns in `a` like this:

```
c = np.array([[1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
              [2, 3, 2, 3, 4],
              [3, 5, 2, 3, 4]])
```

if it helps you can think of the first two columns in `a` as the `x,y` coordinates and `b` as `dx, dy`.

My current method is as follows:

```
c = np.concatenate([a[:, 0:2] + b, a[:, 2:]],1)
```

but I am looking for a better method

Thank you

Comment: `a[:,:2] += b` might be what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) to add zeros to `b` to make its shape the same as `a`'s, then add them:

```
>>> a + np.pad(b, ((0, 0), (0, 3)))
array([[1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 5, 2, 3, 4]])
```

In general (for 2-D):

```
>>> a = np.array([[0, 0, 2, 3, 4],
...               [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
...               [0, 2, 2, 3, 4]])
>>> b = np.array([[1, 1],
...               [2, 2],
...               [3, 3],
...               [4, 4],
...               [5, 5]])
>>> a_shape, b_shape = a.shape, b.shape
>>> max_w = max(a_shape[0], b_shape[0])
>>> max_h = max(a_shape[1], b_shape[1])
>>> padded_a = np.pad(a,
                      ((0, np.abs(a_shape[0] - max_w)),
                       (0, np.abs(a_shape[1] - max_h))))
>>> padded_a
array([[0, 0, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 2, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> padded_b = np.pad(b,
                      ((0, np.abs(b_shape[0] - max_w)),
                       (0, np.abs(b_shape[1] - max_h))))
>>> padded_b
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 5, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> padded_a + padded_b
array([[1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 5, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 5, 0, 0, 0]])
```

In general (2-D, using a `zeros` array and adding to it):

```
>>> c = np.zeros((max_h, max_w), dtype=a.dtype)
>>> c[:a_shape[0], :a_shape[1]] += a
>>> c[:b_shape[0], :b_shape[1]] += b
>>> c
array([[1, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 5, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 4, 0, 0, 0],
       [5, 5, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Padding would be overkill it you can just add `b` to a slice of `a`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thinking about the general case, where both arrays might have to be resized. Although I ended up using another method that uses addition (using a new `zeros` array).